# Kafka Streams Processor API Usage

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Can I use processor api in Kafka Streams and read data from a topic in one kafka cluster and pipe data into a kafka topic in ANOTHER kafka cluster?

Is that do-able thing using processor api? I know, its not possible with Stream DSL!

Comment: It could be possible if you manually create a Producer object yourself within the Processor, but as mentioned, MirrorMaker is the official builtin tool for this

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847690/kafka-streams-connecting-to-multiple-clusters

Comment: If you create your own instance of `KafkaProducer` you will need to go sync writes  to guarantee at-least-once processing. Thus, performance is expected to drop. It's not a recommended pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with Kafka Streams. It only works against a single cluster.

To copy data across clusters you need to either use [MirrorMaker](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_mirror_maker) or one of the available replicator tools, for example a [Kafka source connector](https://github.com/Comcast/MirrorTool-for-Kafka-Connect).

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Is there a way with mirror maker, i can configure the a different topic name in the destination cluster. By default, the script is expecting the topic name to be same in both clusters! Is it possible to change the name in destination cluster ?

Comment: By default, it's not possible with MirrorMaker so you'll have to implement it yourself

Comment: ok. Thanks. One question, Can i write a application using processor api, and stream msgs to another cluster ? any link example programs for processor api you can help with ?