# Can Kafka Streams output topic be on a separate cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-topic

I have a topic where all logs are pushed to centralized topic but I would like to filter out some of those records to a separate topic and cluster if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kafka Streams - connecting to multiple clusters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847690/kafka-streams-connecting-to-multiple-clusters)

Answer (score 6):

Kafka streams not allow to create stream with source and output topics from different Kafka clusters. So the following code will not work for you

```
streamsBuilder.stream(sourceTopicName).filter(..).to(outputTopicName)
```

in this case it expects that outputTopicName is from the same cluster as topic sourceTopicName.

**As a workaround**, in order to send messages into output topic from another cluster, you could **use additionally created KafkaProducer with property `bootstrap.servers` that will point to external cluster and `KStream.foreach()` method**.

```
streamsBuilder.stream(sourceTopicName)
    .filter((key, value) -> ..)
    .foreach((key, value) -> 
        sendMessage(kafkaProducerFromAnotherCluster, destinationTopicName, key, value);


public static void sendMessage(KafkaProducer<String, String> kafkaProducer, 
                               String destinationTopicName, String key, String value) {
    try {
        kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord(destinationTopicName, key, value));
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        log.error(errorMessage, ex);
    }
}
```

**Another option** is to create output topic in your Kafka cluster that will have filtered messages and setup [**Kafka Mirroring**](https://docs.confluent.io/current/multi-dc-replicator/mirrormaker.html) between two clusters (so messages will be copied from one topic to second from another cluster).

Comment: If you create a `KafkaProducer` and us within `foreach()`, you will need to do sync write to the target cluster. Otherwise, you can loose data if something crashes! This will have a performance impact of course. Thus, the recommended approach is, to write the result back into the first cluster, and replicate the result topic into the target cluster.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax do you mean replicate with `Kafka MirrorMaker`?

Comment: `MirrorMaker` is one tool you can use. There are other open-source and proprietary cross-cluster replication tools, too.

Comment: So we cannot create two separate streams with separate connection properties and have one stream write to the other stream? Referring to this: https://docs.confluent.io/3.1.1/streams/concepts.html#processor-topology

Comment: So, KStream stream 2 = stream1.toStream(); stream2.to("OUTPUT_TOPIC"); Or basically that copies the stream connection properties over?

Comment: @user432024 could you please be more specific? which option do you want to use: using KafkaProducer inside foreach or mirroring?

Comment: Neither. I was thinking through stream chaining using toStream(). But I guess the first stream always holds the connection info regardless.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Im in a similar situation. Unfortunately, I dont have write access to origin cluster as it is part of a company wide Kafka cluster. Individual teams cannot make changes to it with their own requirements. So my only options seems to be a producer/consumer duo. As you mentioned, sync will be an issue but I can throw in bounded queues to make it async.